# Confused about GLSL vector matrix multiplication order

Tags: matrix, vector, graphics, webgl, multiplication

I have a matrix that gives you screen coordinates when you plug a vec2 into it.
It produces results like this:
[image]

I can invert the matrix, and plug in mouse coordinates and use that to allow you to place blocks with your cursor

[image]

There is an issue though, if the resolution doesn't follow width=height*2 then you get a messed up image
[image]

Switching the shader so that the matrix is multiplied after the vector fixes this but now the cursor will not be aligned with the block

[image]

Here is the shader code that determines the position (multiplied in this order is what breaks the cursor but fixes resolution bug) :

```
    gl_Position.xy=   a_position.xy  * u_pixelMatrix ;
```

Here is the matrix I am using

```
    26 * renderSettings.blockRotation[0]  / renderSettings.screenSize[0]*0.95
,26 * renderSettings.blockRotation[1] / renderSettings.screenSize[0]*0.95
,12 * renderSettings.blockRotation[2]  / renderSettings.screenSize[1]*0.95
,12* renderSettings.blockRotation[3]  / renderSettings.screenSize[1]*0.95;
```

and here is the coordinates of the mouse position I am supplying to that matrix inverted

```
playerControls.mousePosition[0]/canvas.width-0.5,-playerControls.mousePosition[1]/canvas.height+0.5
```

Also I am using gl-matrix for my matrix invert, and multiply which only allows me to multiply my mouse coordinate vector by a matrix, not vice-versa it seems. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by dividing by screenspace in the shader instead of the matrix